# How to prevent a wrong redirect to login with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, authentication, devise

Hi guys this is probably something simple but I can't find the answer on Google anywhere.
I have a welcome page on my Rails app and when you log in using devise I want to redirect the user from that page directly to the posts page, which is working fine with the code I'm using. The only problem is I cant access that page again once you are logged in because it's obviously redirecting still. Does anyone know if theres a way to redirect when logging in but will still allow you to return to the welcome page if possible?

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if user_signed_in?
      redirect_to :controller=>'posts', :action=>'index'
    end
  end
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  # GET /statuses
  # GET /statuses.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.order('id DESC').paginate(:per_page => 5,:page => params[:page])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show what you have at PostsController#index ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is completely wrong way to redirect the signed_in user to your `Posts` page.

Devise has pretty much good documentation on how to do this - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

You should add following in your `ApplicationController`:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  stored_location_for(resource) || posts_path
end
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know what I would then put in for resource? Thanks for your help

Comment: You mean to put in your `config/routes.rb`? Well, nothing :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is described in documentation of devise https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out

Just define something like in application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    posts_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The Devise

```
before_filter :authenticate_user
```

checks that a user is logged in, and should do what you want. You need to set this filter in your PostsController. See the documentation: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers